# Is it possible to add record without using the auto generated class in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table named 'DEPARTMENT' and has 2 columns, 'DeptID' and 'DeptName'.
I have created properties for that.

```
class DepartmentClass
{
    public int Did { get; set; }
    public string Dname { get; set; }
}
```

Now, instead of using auto generated 'DEPARTMENTs' class, I want to use the above properties to add entry.

```
    DepartmentClass newDept = new DepartmentClass();
        newDept.Did = 120;
        newDept.Dname = "Shell Scripting";
        db.DEPARTMENTs.InsertOnSubmit(newDept);  //this has invalid argument
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

Please let me know if there is any way to make it possible?

Comment: you can try using POCO, which means you would be using the Existing classes and decorate them to create matching table and columns names for Database.

Comment: Are you using entity framework? When you say "auto generated class", does that mean that you are using Database First approach?

Comment: What's the reason why you want this? It's always discouraged to use abbreviations like `Dname`. Why don't you use the generated class?

Comment: Yes I can use the generated class. just wanted to know if there is another approach. :)

Comment: @YacoubMassad I am using LINQ to SQL framework.

Answer (score 0):

if you have alot of these conversions to make, you might try automapper. It's a free tool that can map poco's to data classes and vice versa. What i like about it is that you do the mappings once when the app initializes, then the calls to do the conversion are fairly simple i.e.

```
db.DEPARTMENTs.InsertOnSubmit(Mapper.Map<DEPARTMENTs>(newDept));
db.SubmitChanges();
```

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Link-only answers are likely to be removed in the review process: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: i can't leave comments. i'm not stack overflow cool enough yet, sorry.

Though, i don't see how this doesn't answer the question. it does exactly what he is looking for. maybe you could provide clarification

Comment: i put the example in the context of the posters code. hopefully, that better illustrates how it solves the issue